# Allow facebook to grab Amazon S3 image

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an amazon s3 account which I use to save images. I save images as private so that only my website can fetch them using s3 apis. However, my website has one function that posts updates to facebook.

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
            link: PAGEURL,
            picture: PICTUREURL,
            name: TITLE,
            description: DESCRIPTION
        }, function(response) {
});
```

For this I need the `PICTUREURL`. So my question is how do I make s3 bucket available only to facebook?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can make it available only to Facebook. And even if you could, I don't think that would make the picture visible to visitors. But here goes, anyway.

To make the picture visible to Facebook, use an expiring, pre-signed URL. Instead of sending the regular S3 URL for the PICTUREURL parameter, create a URL that expires in a few minutes (long enough for Facebook to grab the picture) and use that. I'm not sure what language or S3 library you are using, but they all support creation of such a pre-signed URL.

The bad news is that this might not help. That's because Facebook might just use the URL you give it to display the picture, instead of copying the picture and displaying its copy. If so, then the eventual end users will be using the URL you gave Facebook, and it's going to expire before they see it.

Of course, you could use a URL that expires far in the future, but if you do that, you might as well make the S3 objects public in the first place.

Comment: hmm valid points, but is there no way to do this using bucket policies?

Comment: Well, you can't base action on specific AWS accounts, because Facebook doesn't have one (or none that we know, anyway). You can't restrict it to particular IP addresses, because there's no way to know what IP addresses Facebook might use.

If Facebook does just put your URL in their pages, you can use a policy to restrict access to requests that are referred from Facebook URLs. That would do what you want, but not be very secure. It's trivial for anybody to fake the referral header.